# Nested for loop with parameterized cursors is inserting duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

We are using 2 parameterized cursors where the 1st cursor's value is needed in the second cursor to fetch the data accordingly, but it's fetching the values from both cursors. Rather it should fetch from the 2nd cursor only.

Here there are the 2 cursors. From the 1st cursor it needs to fetch the value for attribute 1 and pass it to cursor2 as a parameterized cursor. But while inserting, it's inserting both 1st and 2nd cursor values.

Both actual and expected results are given in the code snippet.

```
/* Table Creation script:*/       
    create table tab1 (order_no number,order_item varchar2(40),header_id number)        
    /        
    create table tab2 (header_id number,line_id number,attribute1 number)        
    /        
    create table final_tab(order_no number, order_item varchar2(40), line_id number)        
    /

    /* Insertion script:*/         
    insert into tab1 values (1,'ABC',12345)
    /
    insert into tab1 values (11,'DEF',34567)
    /
    insert into tab2 values (12345,56789,11)
    /
    insert into tab2 values (12345,23489,11)
    /
    insert into tab2 values (34567,32156,null)
    /
    insert into tab2 values (34567,12534,null)
    /
    commit
    /

    /* Anonymous Block: */
    DECLARE
        CURSOR c1
        IS
            SELECT a.order_no,
                   a.order_item,
                   b.attribute1 end_ord_no,
                   a.header_id,
                   b.line_id
              FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
             WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND a.order_no = 1;
        CURSOR c2 (i_ord_no NUMBER)
        IS
            SELECT a.order_no,
                   a.order_item,
                   a.header_id,
                   b.line_id
             FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
             WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND a.order_no = i_ord_no;
    BEGIN
        FOR c1_rec IN c1
        LOOP
            FOR c2_rec IN c2 (c1_rec.end_ord_no)
            LOOP
                INSERT INTO final_tab (order_no, order_item, line_id)
                     VALUES (c2_rec.order_no, c2_rec.order_item, c2_rec.line_id);
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
        COMMIT;
    END;

/* Actual Result:*/

    Order_NO | Order_Item | Line_id
    11              |  DEF           | 32156
    11              |  DEF           | 12534
    11              |  DEF           | 32156
    11              |  DEF           | 12534

/*Expected Result:*/ 

    Order_NO | Order_Item | Line_id
    11              |  DEF           | 32156
    11              |  DEF           | 12534
```

Comment: Please edit the question, and show the code referenced and where the problem is.

Comment: added the code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your first cursor returns two rows, both of which have the value 11 for `END_ORD_NO`. The second cursor is executed for each of the two rows returned by the first cursor, and each execution of the second cursor returns two rows, values from which are duly inserted into `FINAL_TAB`.

To fix this you should combine your two cursors into a single cursor:

```
SELECT a.order_no,
       a.order_item,
       a.header_id,
       b.line_id
  FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
  WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND
        a.order_no IN (SELECT b.attribute1
                         FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
                         WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND
                               a.order_no = 1)
```

which reduces your code block to

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cc IS
    SELECT a.order_no,
           a.order_item,
           a.header_id,
           b.line_id
      FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
      WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND
            a.order_no IN (SELECT b.attribute1
                             FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
                             WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND
                                   a.order_no = 1);
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN cc LOOP
    INSERT INTO final_tab (order_no, order_item, line_id)
      VALUES (rec.order_no, rec.order_item, rec.line_id);
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

This will not only provide the results you wanted but it will also reduce the chance of errors by simplifying the code, and reduces runtime by eliminating the nested loops.

However, even this can be further simplified to

```
INSERT INTO final_tab (order_no, order_item, line_id)
  SELECT a.order_no,
         a.order_item,
         b.line_id
    FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
    WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND
          a.order_no IN (SELECT b.attribute1
                           FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
                           WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND
                                 a.order_no = 1)
```

This has the advantage that it accomplishes the entire task without requiring the use of any looping, and is faster because the entire operation is performed by the database without having to slow down to interface with an external procedure.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7f7c72c52093f64d1e3dd70e24799b34)

---

## Edit

If you must use both cursors, perhaps you could use a MERGE statement, as follows:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1
    IS
        SELECT a.order_no,
               a.order_item,
               b.attribute1 end_ord_no,
               a.header_id,
               b.line_id
          FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
         WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND a.order_no = 1;
    CURSOR c2 (i_ord_no NUMBER)
    IS
        SELECT a.order_no,
               a.order_item,
               a.header_id,
               b.line_id
         FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
         WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id AND a.order_no = i_ord_no;
BEGIN
  FOR c1_rec IN c1 LOOP
    FOR c2_rec IN c2 (c1_rec.end_ord_no) LOOP
      MERGE INTO FINAL_TAB ft
        USING (SELECT c2_rec.order_no AS ORDER_NO,
                      c2_rec.order_item AS ORDER_ITEM,
                      c2_rec.line_id AS LINE_ID
                 FROM DUAL) d
          ON (ft.ORDER_NO = d.ORDER_NO AND
              ft.ORDER_ITEM = d.ORDER_ITEM AND
              ft.LINE_ID = d.LINE_ID)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (order_no, order_item, line_id)
          VALUES (d.order_no, d.order_item, d.line_id);
    END LOOP;  -- c2_rec
  END LOOP;  -- c1_rec

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but we want to insert the data from both the cursors into final_tab table, so is there any other way to use both the cursors and add separate distinct values to final_tab table.

Comment: Answer edited to include an example of using a MERGE statement to perform a conditional INSERT.